# slider jquery class not being applied until too late

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so simply put ... the simple slider you use the right arrow to go to the next slide and it should immediately apply a class called bounceInUp .... **it does this but not until about 1 second after so you have static text , then the effect and I just want to have the text effect from slide start,**  ...nothing seems to rectify the problem...

I think it may pertain to the transitionend not actually ending until the next slide so was thinking maybe an onclick event for the button itself but i am not sure how to do that...

anyway here is a jsfiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/2ehexp1y/6/)

and here is the jquery , (all is included in the fiddle)

the main jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Store a ref to slides
    var $slides = $(".slides");

    //Bind event to the contianed that gets animated
    $(".slide-container")
    .on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd", function(e){

        // Remove classes from all the elements within the active container that starts with the class 'add-anim'
        $slides.find(".slide-container [class^='add-anin']").removeClass("animated bounceInUp");

        //Add appropriate classes to the matched elements within the active container
        var $radio = $slides.find(":radio[name='radio-btn']:checked");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-up").addClass("animated bounceInUp");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-up-late").addClass("animated bounceInUp");
        $radio.next(".slide-container").find(".add-anim-left").addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button click event is where its at.

You will need to style it the way you want it but I think it does what you want.

**Fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/3hr4ua79/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
  $('.sp').hide();
  $('.active').show();

  $('#button-next').click(function() {

    $('.active').removeClass('active animated bounceInUp').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
      $('.sp').first().addClass('active animated bounceInUp');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active animated bounceInUp');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
  });

  $('#button-previous').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active animated bounceInUp').addClass('oldActive');
    if ($('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
      $('.sp').last().addClass('active animated bounceInUp');
    } else {
      $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active animated bounceInUp');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#slider-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.sp {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
#button-previous {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
#button-next {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  float: right;
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInUp {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 3000px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -5px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
.bounceInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInUp;
  animation-name: bounceInUp;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="sp" style="background: blue;">akjdfalfkdj</div>
    <div class="sp" style="background: yellow;">akjdfautlfkdkjkhkj</div>
    <div class="sp" style="background: green;">akjdfalfkdiyukjkhkj</div>
    <div class="sp" style="background: red;">akjdfalfkdkkljjkhkj</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nav"></div>
<input type="button" id="button-previous" value="Previous">
<input type="button" id="button-next" value="Next">
```